# Error message with Animate?

Tags: animation, code-review

I have a error message, but after I execute ndsolve cell is all right.What is the Reason for this error?

[image]

```
Clear["Global`*"]

{Xx, Yy, Zz} = 
NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == Sin[t], y'[t] == Cos[t], z'[t] == Sin[t], 
x[0] == 3, y[0] == 2, z[0] == \[Pi]/2}, {x, z, y}, {t, 0, 10}]; 

Animate[
Graphics3D[
GeometricTransformation[{Red, Sphere[], Blue, 
Cylinder[{{0, -1.25, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 1/2], Green, 
Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1.25, 0}}, 1/2], Black, 
Cylinder[{{-3, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}}, 1/3]}, 
Composition[RotationTransform[Xx[t], {1, 0, 0}], 
RotationTransform[Yy[t], {0, 1, 0}], 
RotationTransform[Zz[t], {0, 0, 1}]]], Boxed -> False, 
PlotRange -> 3], {{t, 0, "Time"}, 0, 10}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: .............anybody ?

Answer (score 2):

Please take a sheet of paper and draw a circle at the position `{f1[t], f2[t]}`. Do it now!

I guess you are asking how on earth you should know the exact coordinates on the paper without knowing what `f1` and `f2` is, right? *Mathematica* is basically asking the same question about your functions `Xx`, `Yy`, and `Zz` because it just cannot transform a graphical object without know the parameters of the transformation.

Once you evaluate the `NDSolve` line, your unknown functions are filled with real solutions and everything works.

To give you a simple example the reproduces your error message and probably makes the situation clear:

```
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Circle[], 
  ShearingTransform[phi[t], {1, 0}, {0, 1}]]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

It is not possible to shear the circle without knowing the angle...

Comment: And this is the end , there is no solution? Thx. for response. Math software with $162 and No solution.